# Lagrange multiplier associated with the requirement of constant particle number

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, density-functional-theory, functional-derivatives

I am following [Jones and Gunnarsson (1989)](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.61.689). In their paper, readers find the following equation that is often used in many-body quantum physics, in particular density functional theory:
$$
\frac{\delta E}{\delta n} = \frac{\delta T_0}{\delta n} + \frac{ \delta V_\text{ext}}{ \delta n} + \frac{ \delta V_\text{Hartree} }{ \delta n } + \frac{ \delta E_\text{xc} }{ \delta n} = \mu. 
$$
The authors then go on to saying that $\mu$ is a Lagrange multiplier associated with the requirement of constant particle number. This is the bit that I don't understand. I know the ordinary equation of lagrange multipliers however. If you are looking for stationary points of the the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ under the constraint $g(x) = 0$, then there is a number $\lambda$ such that the solutions satisfy $\nabla f(\vec x) = \lambda \nabla g(\vec x)$. Are the authors speaking about something analogous here? How is the condition of constant particle number (the function $g$) defined in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The constraint here is
$$\int_{\rm Volume} {\rm d}^3r \rho(\vec r) = N.$$
Multiplying $\int_{\rm Volume} {\rm d}^3r \rho(\vec r)$ by the Lagrange multiplier $\mu$ and adding this to the Euler-Lagrange equations used to derive e.g. the Kohn-Sham equations, one realizes that $\mu$ corresponds to an energetic term that adds to the eigenenergies. $\mu$ is the Kohn-Sham chemical potential: $\mu$ can be chosen such that occupying the Kohn-Sham states according to Fermi-Dirac statistics will yield the number of particles $N$.

Answer (score 1):

First, the method of Lagrange multipliers involves solving $\nabla f =\lambda \nabla  g$.

Yes, this is a standard (functional) application of the method of Lagrange multipliers. We wish to minimize
$$
 E = \int d^3x\, {\cal E}[n(x)]
$$ 
subject to 
$$
N = \int d^3x\, n(x)\, .  
$$
For this purpose we consider 
$$ 
F = \int d^3x\, {\cal E}[n(x)] - \mu\int d^3x\, n(x)\, ,
$$ 
where $\mu$ is a Lagrange multiplier. We minimize $F$ by making the functional
stationary with respect to $n(x)$. 
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta n}=0 \;\; \rightarrow
 \frac{\delta E}{\delta n}=\mu
$$

Comment: Actually the constraint should be $-\mu \left(  \int d^3x n(x) - N  \right)$. Of course the extremum condition remains the same.